# Merging two 2 tables into 1 C# statement from sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql

Hi guys currently i have this code. I would like to add another field "`GivenName"` into the statement but the issue is it is from another table. How do i merge two database tables into this statement without altering the original query output.

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class frmSales : Form
    {
        public frmSales()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void dtpFrom_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnExtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=abcdefg;Initial Catalog=hello;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=");

                         objConn.Open();

            SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(80), InvDate,3) AS InvDate,InvoiceNo,EmployerCode,TaxAmount + SubTotal AS Amount,'' AS Payment FROM Invoice WHERE (InvDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpFrom.Text + "', 105 )) AND (InvDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpTo.Text + "', 105))", objConn);

            SqlDataReader objReader;
            objReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

            System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("C:\\CMSExportedData\\Sales-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

            int count = 0;
            while (objReader.Read())
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    if (!objReader.IsDBNull(i))
                    {
                        string s;
                        s = objReader.GetDataTypeName(i);
                        //MessageBox.Show(s);
                        if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "char")
                        {
                            sw.Write(objReader.GetString(i));
                        }
                        else if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "money")

                        {
                            sw.Write(objReader.GetSqlMoney(i).ToString());
                        }
                        else if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "nvarchar")
                        {
                            sw.Write(objReader.GetString(i));
                        }
                    }
                    if (i < 4)
                    {
                        sw.Write("\t");
                    }

                }
                count = count + 1;
                sw.WriteLine();

            }
            sw.Flush();
            fs.Close();
            objReader.Close();
            objConn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(count + " records exported successfully.");
            this.Close();
        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dtpTo_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void frmSales_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: More context needed. The "obvious" answer would be an "inner join", but that could affect the rows depending on how the tables would mesh together. For example, if it is 1:1, you'll be fine; if it is 1:? it could remove rows; if it is 1:*, it could remove *or* add rows. Another option is to use a sub-query in the projection. But again; more context. Where would this data come from, and what are the rules for matching?

Comment: In other news, embedding `dtpFrom.Text` directly into the query could be a significant security issue; you should ***absolutely*** parameterize that

Comment: Hi @MarcGravell, Yes i will do parametrize that. I have attached the whole code for your reference

Comment: the extra code is fine, but by "context" I *really* meant: where is `GivenName` coming from? How do you get a `GivenName` from an `Invoice` ?

Comment: No sir `GivenName` is the field i need to get from a table named `PatientDetails`

Comment: fine; now, given an `Invoice`, what information do we have that would get you to `PatientDetails`. Is there a `PatientId` on both, for example? And is it non-nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOIN`:

```
SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(80), InvDate,3) AS InvDate,InvoiceNo,EmployerCode,TaxAmount + SubTotal AS Amount,'' AS Payment 
                                    FROM Invoice inv INNER JOIN
                                         [YourOtherTable] tab ON inv.[SomeID] = tab.[SomeID]
                                    WHERE (InvDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpFrom.Text + "', 105 )) 
                                    AND (InvDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpTo.Text + "', 105))", objConn);
```

`INNER JOIN` if it's a `NOT NULL` column and `LEFT JOIN` when the column is `NULL`.

So you will add this:

```
FROM Invoice inv INNER JOIN
    [YourOtherTable] tab ON inv.[SomeID] = tab.[SomeID]
```

**EDIT:**

Okay, it seems that [MedicalRecordID] is the most obvious.

```
FROM [Invoice] inv INNER JOIN 
[PatientDetails] tab ON inv.[MedicalRecordID] = tab.[MedicalRecordID]
```

Just remember, if you are looking for a specific `PatientDetails` record you will need to add another `AND` to your `WHERE` clause.

Something like:

```
AND tab.[LastName] = 'SomeLastName'
```

**EDIT:**

```
SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(80), inv.[InvDate],3) AS InvDate
                                         , inv.[InvoiceNo]
                                         , inv.[TaxAmount] + inv.[SubTotal] AS Amount
                                         , '' AS Payment 
                                    FROM [Invoice] inv LEFT JOIN 
                                         [PatientDetails] tab ON inv.[MedicalRecordID] = tab.[MedicalRecordID] 
                                    WHERE (inv.[InvDate] >= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpFrom.Text + "', 105 )) 
                                    AND (inv.[InvDate] <= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpTo.Text + "', 105))", objConn);
```

Comment: Hi there, that was a great explanation, but when i tried that, it gave me `The multi-part identifier "inv.GivenName" could not be bound.` error.
  `SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(80), InvDate,3) AS InvDate,InvoiceNo,TaxAmount + SubTotal AS Amount,'' AS Payment FROM Invoice INNER JOIN PatientDetails tab ON inv.GivenName = tab.GivenName WHERE (InvDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpFrom.Text + "', 105 )) AND (InvDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpTo.Text + "', 105))", objConn);`

Comment: @Newbie we already **know** that `inv` doesn't have `GivenName`. We can't see the schema; you need to replace `SomeId` with whatever the join criteria is - for example, CustomerId or PatientId or something. WE CAN'T TELL YOU THAT, because we cannot see the schema.

Comment: @Willem if `GivenName` was in both tables, there would be no need for the join in the first place. I think that the comment above (30 seconds ago) is slightly misleading.

Comment: @Newbie Like Marc stated, you need to JOIN on some key that is present in both tables. Maybe you need to do 2 or 3 JOINS to get to `PatientDetails` form `Invoice`. So look in both tables if you see any column that might be common on both `Invoice` and `PatientDetails`. If you can give the schema's of the two tables we can help you a lot quicker.

Comment: Having some difficulty in retrieving schema. gimme a while

Comment: Patient details:

`SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
      ,[CompanyID]
      ,[DivisionID]
      ,[DepartmentID]
      ,[MedicalRecordID]
      ,[NRIC_New]
      ,[NRIC_Old]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[GivenName]
      ,[DOB]
      ,[Sex]
      ,[Address]
      ,[State]
      ,[PostCode]
      ,[TelHome]`

Comment: Invoice Details:

`[CompanyID]
[DivisionID]
[DepartmentID]
[InvoiceNo]
[AttendedBy]
[InvDate]
[ConsultationFee]
[MedicationFee]
[LabFee]
[RadioFee]
[OtherFee]
[Discount]
[TotalFee]
[CollectedFee]
[MedicalRecordID]
[VisitID]
[Which]
[EmployerName]
[EmployerCode]
[ConsultationMsg]
[PharmacyMsg]
[LaboratoryMsg]
[RadiologyMsg]
[OtherMsg]
[PanelInvoiceNo]
[UserID]
ReceiptID]
[GLTransactionNumber]
[GLTransactionNumberPayment]
[TaxID]
[TaxAmount]
[ProcedureFee]
[ProcedureMsg]
[InvTime]
[Remark]
[SubTotal]
[CopayMethod]`

Comment: @Newbie Okay, it seems that `[MedicalRecordID]` is the most obvious. `FROM Invoice INNER JOIN PatientDetails tab ON inv.[MedicalRecordID] = tab.[MedicalRecordID]`.

Comment: Thanks @Willem for being so patient with me. sorry but it shows `The multi-part identifier "inv.MedicalRecordID" could not be bound.` error now.

Comment: @Newbie Give me your new statement.

Comment: `SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(80), InvDate,3) AS InvDate,InvoiceNo,TaxAmount + SubTotal AS Amount,'' AS Payment FROM Invoice LEFT JOIN PatientDetails tab ON inv.MedicalRecordID = tab.MedicalRecordID WHERE (InvDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpFrom.Text + "', 105 )) AND (InvDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpTo.Text + "', 105))", objConn);
`

Comment: That worked, but it gave me another error. `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`   And vb 2010 pointed to `if(!objReader.IsDBNull(i))`

Comment: @Newbie So now you use your debug skills and sort it out. Read the error. `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` Check the value of `i` and make sure that the given index is present in your array.

Comment: @Willem, thank you for your help. i will try my best to debug. Still learning C#. Much appreciated!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14494/discussion-between-newbie-and-willem)

Answer (score 2):

Change the SQL statement, so that you [JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213233%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) the 2 tables together.  Then, you can access the other column.

Comment: The problem with a join is that we don't know (without additional information) the cardinality involved. This *could* work perfectly, or it could completely change the  rows returned.

Comment: Agreed, this would alter the whole rows returned.

Comment: @Newbie I wouldn't leap to that conclusion; as I tried to emphasise, more context is needed first; it is a *possibility*, not a certainty